# Concentration Inequalities for Low-Dimensional Normal Vector

Tags: multivariate-normal-distribution, high-dimensional

I've got a low-dimensional standard normal vector $g\in\mathbb{R}^n,~~ g\sim\mathcal{N}(0,I_n)$, where $n\le 3$. I want to bound the $L_1$ and $L_2$ norms of $g$ using concentration inequalities (namely Bernstein's inequality), as presented in [Vershynin's book](https://www.math.uci.edu/%7Ervershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.pdf), but I have two problems:

1. The concentration inequality for the norm of a multivariate gaussian $g\sim\mathcal{N}(0,I_n)$ is (Section 3.3.3 of Vershynin): $$P\left(\left|\|g\|_2-\sqrt{n}\right|\ge t\right)\le\exp(-Ct^2)\qquad\text{for all }t\ge0$$ but this is a high-dimensional bound, which will not hold for $n\le 3$.
2. Bernstein's inequality for $n$ independent mean-zero sub-exponential RVs is (Section 2.8 of Vershynin): $$P\left( \left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}{g_i}\right| \ge t \right)\le 2\exp\left( -cn\min\left(\frac{t^2}{K^2},\frac{t}{K} \right)\right)\qquad\text{for every }t\ge0$$ where $K$ is the maximum of sub-exponential norms of $g_i$'s. I am very reluctant to sum $g$'s components, as negative and positive terms would cancel each other. $(0.3,-1,1)$ and $(-0.1,-0.1,-0.1)$ both hold $\left|\frac{1}{N}\sum{X_i}\right|=0.3$ but can't possibly treated equally.

Besides, these, I got no idea where should I bring the constants $C,c$ from.

Any ideas?